# How do I wait for an HTML element to be loaded in a Selenium JavaScript test script

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

The closes thing I could find is `until.elementLocated` but that seems to throw an immediate exception.

Is there any way to wait until an element is loaded in a javascript selenium test script ?

Or is there any way to prevent the exception

```
"NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='NEXT']"}"
```

from being thrown until the timeout has expired ?

```
  await driver.wait(function () {
        let text = "//button[text()='" + "NEXT" + "']";
        let button = By.xpath(text);
        return until.elementLocated(button);
    }, 40000).then(() => {console.log("element is located")})
```

Comment: Try [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: @yusuf - explicit waits throw an immediate exception unless the element is loaded already.  The issue is the browser app is doing some processing and when done displays some results page so I need to wait for this page to be displayed.  It seems there is no way to wait until an element is loaded except by just waiting a long time.  Seems like some fundamental functionality missing from Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly dealing with Selenium in Java or Python, in JS I use Puppeteer or Playwright, so I haven't tested first solution (but I am almost sure it would work).

From documentation, `driver.wait` accepts function and wait for it's condition to be true. So, you can use `findElements` that doesn't throw exception and wait for returned collection length to be more than 0.

```js
const getElements = (locator) => driver.findElements(locator).then(els => els.length);
await driver.wait(() => getElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='NEXT']")), 10000);
```

As an workaround, you can implement your custom waiter that would wait for condition to be true and return element. It's more dirty, however, it would work in any framework.

```js
const waitFor = async (action, timeoutMs, pollIntervalMs) => {
  let isTimeout = false;
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    isTimeout = true;
  }, timeoutMs);
  let result;
  while (!isTimeout && !result) {
    result = await action();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, pollIntervalMs));
  }

  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  if (isTimeout) {
    throw new Error('Timeout exceeded!');
  } else {
    return result;
  }
};

const getElementOrNull = (locator) => driver.findElements(locator).then(els => els.length ? els[0] : null);

const element = await waitFor(() => getElementOrNull(By.xpath("//button[text()='NEXT']")), 10000, 500);
```